# Why does relative line numbering sometimes turn off

Tags: vimrc, line-numbers

I have vim set to relative line numbering with

```
set number
set relativenumber
```

For some reason, every now and then, for some unknown reason, relative line numbering seems to turn off (or is stuck to the top of the buffer) in particular splits (though still active in other splits). Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

This is my full .vimrc as it currently stands

```
execute pathogen#infect()
if has('unix')
   set t_Co=256
endif

" Vundle stuff
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

" Hard Mode Plugin
" autocmd VimEnter,BufNewFile,BufReadPost * silent! call HardMode()

" Other stuff
set number
set noerrorbells   " Turn off the annoying error sounds
set relativenumber " Turn relative line numbering on
set laststatus=2   " Always keep the status line on
set wildmenu       " Create graphical menu when tab completing file paths

" Syntastic
let syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive', 'active_filetypes':   [],'passive_filetypes': [] } " Turn it off for now

"Searching
set incsearch      " Search as characters are entered
set ignorecase     " Ignore case when searching
set smartcase      " If a pattern contains an uppercase letter, it will match case sensitive, otherwise it will be case insensitive

" Setup folding
set foldenable         " Turn folding on
set foldlevelstart=1
set foldmethod=syntax
"
" Backups
set nobackup
set nowritebackup

" Visual elements
set cursorline     " Creates a highlight on the line containing the cursor

" Set Colourscheme from the ./vim/color directory
colorscheme valloric

" Override colours in scheme set below
highlight cursorline ctermbg=17

" Ident guides
let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 0
let g:indent_guides_start_level = 2
let g:indent_guides_guide_size = 1

" let g:indent_guides_enable_on_vim_startup = 1
highlight IndentGuidesEven ctermbg=22
highlight IndentGuidesOdd ctermbg=28

" Identing and tabs
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=3     " Number of visual spaces to visually display hard tabs with
set softtabstop=3 " Number of spaces inserted with the tab key if expandtab is on
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab     " Turn all presses of the tab key into spaces

" Keymaps
map = :set foldlevel+=1<CR>
map - :set foldlevel-=1<CR>

" Swap files
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup//
set directory=~/.vim/swap//
set undodir=~/.vim/undo//
```

Comment: (1) Don't use both pathogen and Vundle.  (2) Don't put comments at end of lines.  As for your question, well, you'd stand better chances to get a meaningful answers if you'd find some way to reproduce the problem reliably.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an idea, but you can find out.

When this happens again, do
`:verbose :set nu? rnu?` and vim should tell you, which plugin turned it off.